# Why is accurate time important with networking?

Tags: ntp

Seems like a broad and vague question and it is but hopefully the below examples can give a better idea of what I'm really questioning.

Recently ran into an issue where because of my system time was out of sync by one day I could not access a private git repository. I heard it was something to do with the certificates.

Then this also reminded me of the time where I was deploying a Kubernetes cluster and the nodes failed to join to the master node because NTP was not setup (and as a result nodes were out of sync).

I believe both cases had a common problem; time not being in sync. And I think it was the certificate that failed to verify maybe?

So my question is, do certificates require machines to be in sync and what are the implications of machines not being in sync (are there security vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific failures you're talking about were likely caused by SSL/TLS certificates which had notBefore or notAfter dates.  These determine the time-span during which the cert is valid.  If your system clock is dramatically wrong, your software may believe a cert has expired or is not yet valid.

The same type of problem can affect two-factor authenticators, clusters of web servers, and many other things.  I'm sure that's why Ron mentions this isn't a topic specific to network engineering; system time sync is very general, as are the problems caused when that time sync is not maintained.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is, do certificates require machines to be in sync and
>   what are the implications of machines not being in sync (are there
>   security vulnerabilities).

Yes, of course the time needs to be synced for certificates, but that is really off-topic here. You can ask about hosts/servers/VMs and protocols above OSI layer-4 on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a business network.

From the perspective of a network engineer (what is on-topic here), having all your network devices synchronized is important for troubleshooting. You need your network devices on a common time in the logs so that you can tell what went on and when.